# How to do this for five subjects

Tags: excel

I have to prepare student marksheet comprising five subjects, and display result as below:

° if student secure more than 33 in 5 subjects show pass.
° if they secure less than 33 in max one subject show re-appear.
° if they secure less than 33 in two or more subject show fail.

How do I do that?

Comment: What language are you using? What are inputs to your program. What are the parameters?

Comment: Show the current layout of the student's result data in the worksheet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is like below:

```
Name    Subject-1   Subject-2   Subject-3   Subject-4   Subject-5   Result
ABC 50  30  33  56  45  Re-Appear
XYZ 33  56  45  22  30  Fail
PQR 56  45  22  32  60  Fail
Test 50 45  33  56  45  Pass
```

[image: Snapshot]

## Formula for result:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:F2,"<33")>=2,"Fail",IF(COUNTIF(B2:F2,"<33")=1,"Re-Appear","Pass"))
```